# Taking distinct rows from datatable fails

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to take distinct rows from my table based on a column value(Column Name `Id`)
my master datatable is like this
[image]
And I want to take all rows with distinct `Id`, My code is like this

```
         DataTable distinctDt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Id", "ProductName", 
    "ProductDescription","ProductCategory_Id", "Fair_Id", "Price","ImagePath", 
"FairName", "FairLogo", "StartDate", "EndDate", "picId");
```

But this still returns duplicate rows. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Because _picID_ has a different value in the two rows?

Comment: @Steve How can I make this only depend on "ID" column and not pic ID?

Comment: Can you omit the picID from the column list?

Comment: @Steve unfortunately its not possible

Comment: And so, what row should survive your UNIQUE constraint? The first one or the second one? This clear conflicts with the concept of UNIQUE. The two rows are not unique. Perhaps it is better to explain what is the problem you are trying to solve with this code

Comment: @Steve I just want one row out of those two which ever it is, it won't affect my other coding logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your used approach is not useful in this scenario because you need all the columns based on the unique columns `ID's`, here is the method of doing this:

```
    public static DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable, string colName)
    {
        Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
        ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();

        //Add list of all the unique item value to hashtable, which stores combination of key, value pair.
        //And add duplicate item value in arraylist.
        foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
        {
            if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]))
                duplicateList.Add(drow);
            else
                hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty);
        }

        //Removing a list of duplicate items from datatable.
        foreach (DataRow dRow in duplicateList)
            dTable.Rows.Remove(dRow);

        //Datatable which contains unique records will be return as output.
        return dTable;
    }
```

Simply pass your MasterDatatable and column name to this method and it will give you what you want.

It is tested code and works perfectly. See the working.
[image: Execution]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've tested this with duplicates but it gave me unique results based on ID.